# Using time command for benchmarking

Tags: bash, time, benchmarking

I'm trying to use the `time` command as a simple solution for benchmarking some scripts that do a lot of text processing and makes a number of network calls. To evaluate if its a good fit, I tried doing:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "\n%E elapsed,\n%U user,\n%S system, \n %P CPU, \n%M
max-mem footprint in KB, \n%t avg-mem footprint in KB, \n%K Average total
(data+stack+text) memory,\n%F major page faults, \n%I file system
inputs by the process, \n%O file system outputs by the process, \n%r
socket messages received, \n%s socket messages sent, \n%x status"  yum
install nmap
```

and got:

```
1:35.15 elapsed,
3.17 user,
0.40 system,
 3% CPU,
0 max-mem footprint in KB,
0 avg-mem footprint in KB,
0 Average total (data+stack+text) memory,
127 major page faults,
0 file system inputs by the process, 
0 file system outputs by the process,
0 socket messages received,
0 socket messages sent,
0 status
```

which is not exactly what I was expecting - specially the 0 values. Even when I change the command to say `ping google.com`, the socket messages are 0. What's going on? Is there any alternative?

[And I'm confused if it should stay here or be posted in serverfault]

Comment: The time command can only output values if the tracking has been compiled into the kernel. I don't even know if any tracking code has ever been written for these particular parameters...

Comment: Try strace for counting the socket calls

Comment: Yeah I was trying `strace -c` ... trying to figure out how to grep is data to the abstraction level that I need.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not working with Linux; I assume you're using Linux since you said "strace". The manual page says:

```
Bugs

Not all resources are measured by all versions of Unix,
so some of the values might be reported as zero. The present
selection was mostly inspired by the data provided by 4.2 or
4.3BSD.
```

I tried "wget" on an OSX system (which is BSD-ish) to check if it report socket statistics, and there at least socket works:

```
0.00 user,
0.01 system, 
 1% CPU, 
0 max-mem footprint in KB, 
0 avg-mem footprint in KB, 
0 Average total (data+stack+text) memory,
0 major page faults, 
0 file system inputs by the process, 
0 file system outputs by the process, 
151 socket messages received, 
8 socket messages sent, 
0 status
```

Hope that helps,
Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `time` to benchmark. Some of the fields of the `time` command is broken as specified in [1]. However the basic functionality of time (real , user and cpu time) are still intact.

[1] [Maximum resident set size does not make sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035232/maximum-resident-set-size-does-not-make-sense)

Comment: interesting! thanks for sharing - I've moved away from being lazy and trying to benchmark stuff with the time command.